# How can I solve space derivative in open modelica?

Tags: modelica, derivative, calculus, pde, openmodelica

In OPEN MODELICA:

I have an partial derivative equation,
Q=-A*dy/dx,

For time derviative,Q=-A*dy/dt - I can use code Q=-A*der(y);

Is there a way to code space derivative or is this the same?

Comment: Same question with more context here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58362001/discretizing-pde-in-space-for-use-with-modelica

Answer (score 0):

According to "Introduction to Modeling and Simulation of Technical and Physical Systems with Modelica", PDEs are not supported in Open Modelica.

[image]